# htaccess redirect referrer - but stop redirecting on new page

Tags: .htaccess, regex

We have a problem with someone poaching the extensive ukulele song list at http://scorpex.net/Uke for a paid app.

Negotiations have broken down so any requests from the app are going to be redirected to a new "these songs are being ripped off" pdf file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^theapp [NC]
RewriteRule \.*$ http://scorpex.net/stop/stealing/uke/songs/please.pdf [R]
```

The problem is it creates a redirect loop - I can see why, I am not sure how to resolve it.  Ideas people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions: Only apply the rule if the filename doesn't contain please.pdf.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^theapp [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !please.pdf
RewriteRule \.*$ http://scorpex.net/stop/stealing/uke/songs/please.pdf [R,L]
```

or only do the redirect when the user tries to access an mp3 file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^theapp [NC]
RewriteRule \.mp3$ http://scorpex.net/stop/stealing/uke/songs/please.pdf [R,L]
```

Comment: It is actually PDF files they are stealing.  But, that is a more elegant solution - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your Rewrite rules should look something like this I believe:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*theapp.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://scorpex.net/stop/stealing/uke/songs/please.pdf [R]
```

Comment: I am testing that from my own domain but still looping: http://hinternet.com.au/redirect.php htaccess is displayed there.

Comment: Trying to learn something:  Isn't the problem that it does the redirect and when it gets to the redirect page it follows .htaccess rule and redirects again...and again until it times out.  So somehow the redirect needs a break or something.  Or am I way off the mark?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the right or even the best solution, but this works:

In the target directory I added another .htaccess with `RewriteEngine Off`  I am not experienced with either regexp or .htaccess but can muddle my way through by following examples so I am interested in comments about this approach.